# Using v-if to show the first render, then v-show?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I know the difference between v-if and v-show, so I was wondering, is there any way that I could extract the best of them:
-v-if doesn't load on immediate render;
-v-show keeps the component alive, so it's faster to toggle.
Is it possible to delay the render, then keeping it alive once it's activated? And it is efficient as it seems?

Comment: Assign both `v-if` and `v-show`. Keep `v-if` initially `false` .. once `v-if` turn `true`, keep it `true` always and use `v-show` to hide/show.

Comment: With a function this should do it. What about performance, is it really viable?

Comment: Performance really depends on how many such elements you have on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Aditya Bhave's comment, I created this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="initiated === true" v-show="showComponent"></div>
  
    <button @click="toggleComponent">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      initiated: false,
      showComponent: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComponent () {
      this.initiated = true
      this.showComponent = !this.showComponent
    },
  }
}
</script>
```